# How can I move the Windows 8 on-screen keyboard?

Tags: windows-8, on-screen-keyboard

From the first look, it seems that the onscreen keyboard in Windows 8 cannot be moved from its default position at the bottom of the screen:

[image: onscreenkeyboard]

However, sometimes it obstructs the input field and should be repositioned (see iOS 5's [screenshots](http://ipadinsight.com/ios/ipad-keyboard-in-ios-5-split-it-move-it-up-and-down-the-page-dock-it/) for examples)

So the question is, can it actually move? If it can, how can I do that? If it cannot, is it possible to use the keyboard to fill an input field that is underneath it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keyboard you are using has two modes - docked and undocked:

- In docked mode, the keyboard locks to the bottom of the screen, as per your screenshot.
- In undocked mode, you can drag it around the screen as necessary.

To switch between the two modes, click this button:

[image: Undock button on new-style on-screen keyboard]

Alternatively, you can use the on-screen keyboard that used to be an accessibility feature in previous versions of Windows. To launch this, open the Start screen and type `keyboard`, then select this application:

[image: Search for keyboard]

This will appear as a desktop window instead, and has a larger choice of buttons:

[image: Old-style on-screen keyboard]

Answer (score 2):

1. Press the "Options" key.
   [image]
2. Check the "Show keys to make it easier to move around the screen" option.
   [image]
3. Use the navigation keys to move the keyboard.
   [image]

Note that if I search for "keyboard" from the Start Screen, then select the "On-screen keyobard" app, it appears in a window that I can move around. I am using full Windows 8, not Windows 8 RT, so this may have something to do with it.