# How can I enter text behind the touch keyboard in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, touch-keyboard, virtual-keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Move Windows 8 onscreen keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/496475/move-windows-8-onscreen-keyboard)

Some web sites have a problem in desktop Internet Explorer 10, where they don't flow up behind the virtual keyboard.

What can I do to keep the virtual keyboard up and type easily without re-sizing the browser window?